# ASP.NET Core self-contained exe

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want my ASP.NET Core Web API to run as a self-contained exe within the .NET framework and not .NET Core Framework. Is that possible? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

If I add `"net451": {}` to my frameworks section in project.json, 
I get the following exception:

```
Failed to make the following project runnable: myProject (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) reason: Expected coreclr library not found in package graph. Please try running dotnet restore again.
```

Comment: The answer is yes. I presume the "how" is implicit: use OWIN and use net45 as target framework. Those are technically two questions and you can easily find the answer if you search. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/869223/asp-net-web-api-create-a-self-hosted-owin-based-we

Comment: If you use ASP.NET Core and target net46 in your project.json, you have nothing to do. Just run a ```dotnet publish```. That will generate an .exe file in the publish folder.

Comment: @Stefanod'Antonio: I think you are confusing self-hosting with self-contained

Comment: @Kalten: Same for you. The question is about self-containing, not self-executing/self-hosting http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd. Self-containing means there is no additional installation required (i.e. of a runtime) because the runtime is shipped with the application. This is not true for .NET 4.x and only possible with .NET Core (since its modular)

Comment: @Tseng a self-contained exe must be self-hosting and vice versa. How do you would you use an exe with IIS? If marrschine wrote self contained only I would have agreed.

Comment: "Self contained" means you can package the app in a zip file and unzip it on other computer and run. That's not possible with .NET 4.x applications, because a requirement is that .NET >=4.5 must be installed. In .NET Core you can ship the framework with your application, no installation required. Self-hosting/executing only means you can start it without another tool, but runtime still may be required. When runtime is required, its called portable app. Having said that, every ASP.NET Core application is a self-hosting one, as only two hosting models exist: Kestrel or Weblistener

Comment: Yet, a self contained exe is still also self-hosted otherwise it wouldn't be an exe. So the answer is no unless the author means (as I believe) self-hosted.

Comment: You can't create a self-contained exe with ASP.NET Core when targeting .NET 4.x. The runtime always needs to be installed on the OS where you want to run it. A self-contained application has no external prerequisites which needs to be installed before you can run it. Try running an ASP.NET Core application which targets .NET 4.5 on a system w/o .NET 4.5 installed and see what happens ;)

Comment: @Tseng You are just repeating your comment and my comment. This is pointless.

Comment: Cause you don't understand it. Read the linked documentation: _For a self-contained deployment, you deploy not only your app and any third-party dependencies, **but the version of .NET Core that you build your app with**_. You are just using misunderstanding the term "self-contained" and confuse it with "executable" or "self-hosting". And the above is **not possible** with .NET 4.x!

Comment: @Tseng again, the broken record... Re-read my comment and maybe you'll understand why you're making a pointless discussion or maybe not. Up to you.

Comment: I don't need to reread it, you need to read the linked article. Slowly and understand its content. Your comment and the linked article are just completely unrelated to the question asked. You just stand wrong in any possible way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a self-contained app which targets .NET Framework >=4.5, because the full .NET Framework isn't modular and its not possible to have more than one version of it installed. Newer versions basically always replace the previous one.

Self-contained apps were one main motivation for .NET Core (together with portability)

You **ALWAYS** have to install .NET >=4.5 before your app can run. self-contained apps only work with .NET Core because .NET core libraries can be pulled through nuget package.

For .NET 4.6 you can only create portable apps, which is the default mode.

Comment: I think you might have meant .NET <= 4.5.

Comment: @GlennSills: I meant what I said ;) ASP.NET Core is based on `System.Runtime` which is only available with .NET 4.5. So ASP.NET Core can't run on any .NET Framework older than 4.5 because of this. .NET 4.5 is still one monolithic framework and can not be run side-by-side because its not modular. You always have to install it before you can run a .NET application on it. .NET Core is different. You can package everything together (Framework and application), so that merely unzipping the application will make it work w/o installing the specific runtime

Comment: Basically: Portable Apps = require runtime to be installed, smaller deployment. Self-contained apps = require no run time installation, but size of the deployment grows (because it the framework libraries need to be deployed with the app)

Comment: So, if I've understood correctly the .exe is not really self-contained, it is the directory containing the .exe that is self contained. There is no way to create a single .exe with everything statically bound into one file.

Comment: @GGleGrand: Self-contained in context of .NET Core refers to the ability to run without .NET Core runtime being installed on the system, because in this case the required .NET Core system libraries will be packaged with the application. In a portable .NET Core app this is different. The runtime packages won't be shipped with the application and require .NET Core to be installed before you can run the application on another system. As far as I know there is no way to create a single exe containing it all, except maybe ILMerge (google it), but not sure this still works with .NET Core

Comment: Thanks. I also found a comment to this extent by Shawn in http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SelfcontainedNETCoreApplications.aspx OK, gzipping now...